# nodejs q won't resolve

Tags: node.js, q

When I query for a user, q won't resolve my promise (or my then-function won't pick it up). I'm getting all the debug output until I get to the debug output in the then-function of the user controller. There the debug output just stops.

When I try to call the get from inside the user model, there is no problem with the resolve. It just resolves fine. the problem only occurs when stepping back to the user controller.

User controller

```
var UserModel        = require('../model/user.model');

function UserController () {}

UserController.prototype.get = get;

function get (req, res, next) {

    UserModel.get('54c1b6c7-193e-4cb6-aa17-37d1f0a8fc7b').then(function (response) {
        debug(response);
        res.send('ok');
    }, function (response) {
        debug(response);
        res.send('not ok');
    });
}

module.exports = new UserController();
```

User model

```
var mysql       = require('mysql'),
    config      = require('config'),
    Q           = require('q'),
    debug       = require('debug')('user.model'),
    BaseModel   = require('./base.model'),
    connection  = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : config.get('database.host'),
        user     : config.get('database.user'),
        password : config.get('database.password'),
        database : config.get('database.database')
    }),
    sql;

function UserModel () {
    BaseModel.setConnection(connection);
}

UserModel.prototype.get = get;


function get(id) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id LIKE ' + connection.escape(id);

    BaseModel.query(sql, function (results) {
        debug(results[0]);

        endConnection();

        deferred.resolve(results[0]);
    }, function () {
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

module.exports = new UserModel();
```

Base model

```
var debug       = require('debug')('base.model'),
    connection;

function BaseModel () {}

BaseModel.prototype.setConnection   = setConnection;
BaseModel.prototype.query           = query;

function setConnection (con) {
    connection = con;
}

function query(sql, callback, errorCallback) {
    callback        = callback || undefined;
    errorCallback   = errorCallback || undefined;

    debug('query: ' + sql);

    connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            debug(error);

            if (errorCallback) {
                errorCallback();
            }

            return;
        }

        if (callback) {
            callback(results, fields);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = new BaseModel();
```

Anyone any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should add a `catch` to your promise.  Also, why are you using q? Just use regular promises or bluebird or https://github.com/lukeb-uk/node-promise-mysql

Comment: I've found the problem, debug wasn't declared in my usercontroller and the code crashed without notice.